# OpenCV and C, Bad argument (response #0 is not integral) in cvPreprocessCategoricalResponses

Tags: c, opencv, svm, mat

hi guys i m stuck on this error while running my program.

I created a float matrix of values with this function

```
void calcolaSubpixel(IplImage *GT, costi ** totalCostMatrix, float ** subpixelM, int h, int w){
    int modulo;
    int subpixel;
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < w; j++) {
             //TODO i valori ottneuti vanno 0-1, io li voglio da -0.5,0.5
             int modulo = (CV_IMAGE_ELEM(GT, ushort, i, j))%256;
             float subpixel01 = modulo/256.0f;
             subpixelM[i][j] = subpixel01;
        }
    }
}
```

and then i put them in an array of float with this function

```
void fillLabels( IplImage *GT, float** subpixelM, float * labels){
    int h = GT->height, w = GT->width;
    int i,j,L = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < w; j++) {
        //se il pixel in esame della ground truth non ha intensita 0 lo considero,
        //altrimenti lo inserisco nella label:
            if (CV_IMAGE_ELEM(GT, ushort, i, j) != 0) {     
                labels[L] = subpixelM[i][j];
                L++;
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

and use this array labels for a `Mat labelsMat(nRighe, 1, CV_32FC1, labels);` where nRighe is a value calculated before to teach a SVM

```
CvSVM SVM;
SVM.train(trainingDatasMat, labelsMat, Mat(), Mat(), params);
```

trainingDatasMat doesn t give me any trouble, but labelsMat, built like that' return

> OpenCV Error: Bad argument (response #0 is not integral) in cvPreprocessCategoricalResponses, file /home/vision/opencv-2.4.11/modules/ml/src/inner_functions.cpp, line 715
>       terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception' what():  /home/vision/opencv-2.4.11/modules/ml/src/inner_functions.cpp:715: error: (-5) response #0 is not integral in function cvPreprocessCategoricalResponses

any suggestion to overcome this problem ? thank you

this is the main

```
#include "cost.h"
#include "disparity.h"
#include "fixed_window.h"
#include "confidence.h"
#include "utils.h"
#include "stereoPipeline.h"
#include "interpolation.h"
#include "SGM.h"
#include "learning.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cv.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int dMax=15;
if (argc != 4)
{
    printf("Usage: %s <image_id> <gaps> < <algo>\n", argv[0]);
    return -1;
}
int id=atoi(argv[1]);

//sistema l'id per evitare problemi con il numero di cifre
char q[10];
if(id < 10){sprintf(q, "00%d", id); }
if(id >= 10 && id <= 99){sprintf(q, "0%d", id); }
if(id >= 100){sprintf(q, "%d", id); }

int gaps=atoi(argv[2]);
int algo=atoi(argv[3]);

IplImage *L, *R, *GT;
// ***********************************************************
// ***********************************************************
// ******       STEREO ALGORITHM        ******
// ***********************************************************
// ***********************************************************
char filenameL[100];
char filenameR[100];
char filenameGT[100];


//carico il nome delle immagini
sprintf(filenameL,"/KITTI/image_0/000%s_10.png",q);
sprintf(filenameR,"/KITTI/image_1/000%s_10.png",q);
sprintf(filenameGT,"/KITTI/disp_occ/000%s_10.png",q);


// load grayscale images
L = cvLoadImage(filenameL, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
R = cvLoadImage(filenameR, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
GT= cvLoadImage(filenameGT, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED );     

dMax=kitti_dMax(GT);


int h = L->height, w = L->width;
IplImage* DisparityL = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(L),8,1);
IplImage* DisparityR = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(R),8,1);

t_DSI* DSI=create_DSI(w,h,dMax);
t_DSI *boxFilteredDSI=create_DSI(w,h,dMax);
t_DSI* outDSI=create_DSI(w,h,dMax);


// point-wise cost (Absolute Difference or Hamming distance on Census transforms)
if (algo == 0)
    AbsoluteDifferenceCost(L, R, dMax, DSI);    
else    
    HammingDistanceCost(L, R, dMax, 5, DSI);

// TAD aggregation
BoxFiltering(DSI, boxFilteredDSI, 5, 100);

disparity_map(boxFilteredDSI,DisparityL, true);
disparity_map_R(boxFilteredDSI,DisparityR, true);   
// show results
/*cvShowImage("Left",L);
cvShowImage("FW Left",DisparityL);
cvShowImage("FW Right",DisparityR);
cvWaitKey(0);*/

//matrice disparità
int **disparityMatrix;
disparityMatrix= (int **) calloc(h,sizeof(int *));
int z=0;
for (z;z<h;z++){
disparityMatrix[z]=(int *) calloc(w,sizeof (int ));
}

//matrice dei costi
costi ** totalCostMatrix;
totalCostMatrix= (costi **) calloc(h,sizeof(costi *));
for (z=0;z<h;z++){
    totalCostMatrix[z]=(costi *) calloc(w,sizeof (costi ));
}


SGM(boxFilteredDSI, outDSI, dMax, 30, 300, 255);
disparity_map(outDSI,DisparityL, true);
disparity_map_R(outDSI,DisparityR, true);

//findtotalcost riempie la matrice ---->> test con outdSI usata per SGM
findTotalCost(outDSI,totalCostMatrix);

int nRighe = linesLength(GT);
printf ("\n\n%d\n", nRighe);
float * labels;
labels = (float *) calloc(nRighe, sizeof(float));
float ** trainingDatas;
trainingDatas = (float **) calloc(nRighe, sizeof(float *));
for (z=0;z<nRighe;z++){
    trainingDatas[z] = (float *) calloc(3, sizeof(float));
}

//matricisubpixels
float ** subpixelM;
subpixelM= (float **) calloc(h,sizeof(float *));
for (z=0;z<h;z++){
    subpixelM[z]=(float *) calloc(w,sizeof (float ));
}

//riempio i vettori labels e traingDatas
//labels -> valori della GT
//traingDatas -> i costi
calcolaSubpixel(GT, totalCostMatrix, subpixelM, h, w);
fillLabels(GT, subpixelM, labels);
fillTrainingdatas(GT, totalCostMatrix, trainingDatas);



//test
labels[5] = 1.0;
//trainingDatas[0][0] = 1;
//trainingDatas[0][1] = 1;
//trainingDatas[0][2] = 1;


//imposto le label e i dati di training per effettuare il learning
Mat labelsMat(nRighe, 1, CV_32FC1, labels);
Mat trainingDatasMat(nRighe, 3, CV_32FC1, trainingDatas);

// Set up SVM's parameters
CvSVMParams params;
params.svm_type    = CvSVM::C_SVC;
params.kernel_type = CvSVM::LINEAR;
params.term_crit   = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 1e-6);

// Train the SVM
CvSVM SVM;
SVM.train(trainingDatasMat, labelsMat, Mat(), Mat(), params);
```

Comment: Can you post the code for how you set up params?

Comment: Not the answer, but try `sprintf(q,"%03d"....`

Comment: thank mark, but the part above //findtotalcost riempie la matrice ---->> test con outdSI usata per SGM came from another file which works fine

Answer (score 0):

With these settings for SVM, all the values in labelsMat must be integral.  A possible solution would be to remove the following line from calcolaSubpixel.

```
float subpixel01 = modulo/256.0f;
```

However, there are possibly other problems with your code as well.  One in particular is that if you want to initialize a cv::Mat with a data pointer, then that pointer has to be a pointer to contiguous memory for the desired underlying type (respecting the dimensions and step size).  In your code, the data pointer is set to an array of float* pointers (trainingDatas is a float**).  A correct way to do this would be to pass a float* (pointing to `nRighe*3` floats) to the constructor for `trainingDatasMat`.

That being said an easier way would be to allow cv::Mat to do the memory management for you.  Something along the lines of the following:

```
Mat trainingDatasMat(nRighe, 3, CV_32FC1);
fillTrainingdatas(GT, totalCostMatrix, (float*) trainingDatasMat.data);
```